# The fastest "find"er of them all?

Tags: algorithm, c, file, reinventing-the-wheel, homework

For part of a project, I was given this directive:

> The find command will use the directory (dirent) function calls, but
>   will require you to start at a directory and then determine if a file
>   is a directory or a file and if it is a directory you will need to
>   walk down that directory as well. You will need a method/algorithm to
>   note the new directories and build a logical graph or thread out every
>   directory to find if the filename is in that directory and display the
>   "absolute" path to that file.

I thought the [`nftw()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/rnftw.htm) function would be optimal for this, and I believe it makes my application pretty robust and fast.  On my Mac (ommiting 196 lines of filename output each):

```
$ time find ../../ -name "CMakeLists.txt"
real    0m0.337s
user    0m0.025s
sys 0m0.292s

$ time ./my_find ../../ -name "CMakeLists.txt"
real    0m0.326s
user    0m0.022s
sys 0m0.278s
```

**find.c**:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef streq
#define streq(x, y) (strcmp((x), (y)) == 0)
#endif

typedef enum {SUCCESS, INVALD_DIR, OPENDIR_ERR, NFTW_ERR} Return;

const char* str = NULL;

int check_path(const char* path)
{
    DIR* dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir)  // directory exists
    {
        closedir(dir);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ENOENT == errno) // directory doesn't exist
        return INVALD_DIR;
    else // opendir failed for some other reason
        return OPENDIR_ERR;
}

int callback(const char *file, const struct stat *sb, int flag, struct FTW *s)
{
    int err = 0;
    const char *name = file + s->base;

    switch (flag)
    {
        case FTW_F:
            if (streq(name, str))
                puts(file);
            break;
        case FTW_D:
        case FTW_DNR:
        case FTW_SL:
        case FTW_NS:
            break; // continue as normal
        case FTW_DP:
        case FTW_SLN:
        default:
            err = NFTW_ERR; // error occured
            break;
    }

    return err;
}

int process(const char* path)
{
    int err = nftw(path, callback, getdtablesize(), 0);
    return err;
}

void usage(const char* prog_name)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "usage: %s [path] -name <name>\n", prog_name);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 4)
        usage(argv[0]);

    const char* path = argv[1];
    str = argv[3];

    int err = check_path(path);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: %s\n", argv[0], path, strerror(errno));
        return err;
    }
    else
        process(path);

    return err;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your solution, it's clever & fast, however I can't help but feel like it goes against the spirit of the assignment.  You've found a built in system call that greatly simplifies what it is your need to do, **which is great**, but in doing so you've delegated the algorithm, which may not be what is expected from the assignment.

The assignment reads as if it's expecting your to use things like `opendir` and `readdir` to iterate through the folders yourself.  You would then be responsible for maintaining state, and writing the iteration algorithm.

**-name or not -name**

Your argument handling is also a little bit on the naive side.  Should I really be able to run it like this:

```
./my_find ../../ -ThisArgumentIsNeverCheckedSoICanPutPrettyMuchAnything "CMakeLists.txt"
```

Why both having the second argument if you're not going to check it, it's just extra typing...

**Wildcards**

It's not really clear from the spec, however the built in 'find' command supports wildcards.  Your current implementation doesn't appear to (you're only doing an exact match).